# Upload mutliple images with progress shown ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a progress bar for multiple images. The php code works fine and uploads the images to my dropbox account but after adding in a progress bar code only the first image shows the progress bar and after that an error msg the displayed. The first file also doesn't upload after the error appears.

Error msg: 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...... progressbar/processupload.php on line 30

I'm thinking it has to do with the ajax .file[0] in **var file = _("file1").files[0]**; This is my first time dealing with ajax. Any ideas?

HTML & JS

```
<script>    
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    // alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "processupload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function progressHandler(event){
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
    _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
    _("progressBar").value = 0;
}
function errorHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}
function abortHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="upload" id="upload" action="processupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>File to upload : <input type ="file" name = "file1[]" id="file1" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"></p><br />       
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
    <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
    <h3 id="status"></h3>
    <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
</form>
```

PHP processupload

```
<?php   
    // Include the Dropbox SDK libraries
    require_once "dropbox-sdk/Dropbox/autoload.php";
    use \Dropbox as dbx;

    // grant access
    $accessToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
    $accountInfo = $dbxClient->getAccountInfo();

    //set parameters
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp", "psd","ai","pdf");
    $max_file_size = 1024*60000; //60000 kb/60mb
    $count = 0;

    $fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
    $fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
    $fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
    $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true

    //loop through each file
    foreach ($_FILES["file1"]["name"] as $f => $name){
        if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"][$f] == 4) {
            echo "error";
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }   
        if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES["file1"]["size"][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }
            else{ // No error found! Upload file to dropbox 
                echo "10";
                /* Copy file to dropbox */
                $f2 = fopen($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"][$f], "rb");
                echo "20";
                //get file name
                $target_file = basename($_FILES["file1"]["name"][$f]);
                //get file extension
                $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 

                $result = $dbxClient->uploadFile("/AEE1292838/101/" . $target_file, dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f2);
                fclose($f2);                    
                echo ($result[size]);               

                $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
            }
        }
    }
?>
```